# How to upload svg data using multipart/form-data?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload SVG data using `fetch` API and `multipart/form-data` `content-type` but its throwing 400 error code.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("front_svg",stage.canvas.toSVG());
var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: formData,
    redirect: 'follow'
};
fetch("api-url", requestOptions).then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: can you also share what error you see other than 400 error code?

Comment: @swapyonubuntu No error in console except this. When I send as blob then I get CORS error.

Comment: you should see error message in console log right?

Comment: @swapyonubuntu Unfortunately I do not get error in console.log